# Cargar datos formateados en JTable

Tags: java, sql, jtable, numberformat

estoy leyendo varios datos de sql server a java; todos los datos son varchar excepto 1 que es de tipo decimal en el sql server. Una vez leido los datos en java estoy tratando de cargar en un jtable, pero quisiera el tipo de dato decimal (double en java) se cargue en el jtable con el formato "###,##0.00", pero me carga el error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,105.00". Les muestro el código que estoy usando. Gracias por su tiempo

```
PagosSinDescuento pagos;  
ArrayList<PagosSinDescuento> lsPagos = new ArrayList<>();
DecimalFormatSymbols simbolo=new DecimalFormatSymbols();  
simbolo.setDecimalSeparator('.');  
simbolo.setGroupingSeparator(',');  
DecimalFormat formateador = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00",simbolo);

while(rs.next()){  
            pagos=new PagosSinDescuento();  
            pagos.setNombres(rs.getString(1));  
            pagos.setQuincena(rs.getString(2));                                 
            pagos.setMonto(rs.getDouble(3));  
            pagos.setDescuento(rs.getString(4));                
            lsPagos.add(pagos);  
        }

Object[] fila = new Object[modelo.getColumnCount()];   
 for (int i = 0; i < lsPagos.size(); i++) {  
 fila[0] = lsPagos.get(i).getNombres();  
 fila[1] = lsPagos.get(i).getQuincena();  
 double d= lsPagos.get(i).getMonto();  
 System.out.println("Monto leido del sql:"+d);  
 String d2=formateador.format(d);  
 System.out.println("Monto con formato:"+d2+"\n");   
 fila[2] = d2;  
 fila[3] = lsPagos.get(i).getDescuento();  
 modelo.addRow(fila);  
 }  
TablaPagosFaltantes.setModel(modelo);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: debes convertir el dato double a string si desea ingresar el dato a un jtable

Comment: Hola DanRod, al formatear el dato double estoy convirtiendo a un String antes de cargar el valor en el JTable

Comment: Estoy usando Netbeans 8.2, según he probado en las columnas 1; 2 y 5 de la tabla me permite ingresar los datos formateados, pero en las columnas 3 y 4 solo me permite ingresar datos de tipo numérico, recalco que todas las columnas de la tabla está declarado como Object. No tengo ni la menor idea porque sucede esto, a veces pienso que el IDE está fallando.